# Wordpress shows wrong custom menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

When I'm trying to show either one of my secondary menus in Wordpress it will display the primary menu ('main-menu') again instead of `'footer-menu'` or `'info-menu'`. I use the following code to display my menu:

```
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme-location' => 'info-menu',
                    'depth'      => 1,
                    'container'  => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav-info',
                    'fallback_cb' => 'wp_page_menu')
                );
```

And I registered my menus in `function.php`:

```
function register_my_menu() {

    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'ibasketball' ),
            'footer-menu' => __( 'Footer Menu', 'ibasketball' ),
            'info-menu' => __( 'Info Menu', 'ibasketball' )
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code `theme-location` should be `theme_location`
Try `wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'info-menu'));`    it will work

Answer (score 0):

From codex, there is only one parameter available in `register_nav_menus`

Usage

```
 <?php register_nav_menus( $locations ); ?>
```

Parameters

```
$locations

(array) (required) An associative array of menu location slugs (key) and descriptions (according value).
Default: None
```

Refer codex for more detail [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus)